# 'getClass()' in Byte Buddy Example

Tags: java, eclipse, byte-buddy

I took the following example code from the Byte Buddy site and pasted it into Eclipse:

```
Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
      .subclass(Object.class)
      .make()
      .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
      .getLoaded();
```

`getClass()` is errored by the syntax checker with the message:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is specified in a static method - you didn't include it, but "Cannot make a static reference" is a give-away.

Move your code into an instance method, and invoke it from there.  If you're currently doing this from a `main` method, change it to the following.

```
public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this method is static - see the key word in the signature
        new ExampleClass().execute();
    }

    public void execute() {
        // this is an instance method
        Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
                              .subclass(Object.class)
                              .make()
                              .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                              .getLoaded();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the how you get the class from `getClass()` to the static reference `ExampleClass.class`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you copied the code into your static main method.

Since **the method is static, you cannot use the instance method `getClass()`**.

Instead access the classloader like this:

```
YourClassName.class.getClassLoader()
```

You can find more info on Class Literals in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).